# How to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin^{k}(x)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

I was given an exercise:

> Calculate 1+$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin^{k}(x)}$

I recognize $$\sin(kx)=Im(cis(kx))=Im(cis^{k}(x))$$ and $$\sin^{k}(x)=(Im(cis(x)))^{k}$$
 but I do not know how to proceed .

I would appreciate any help or hint on how to get started, I guess
that is should be related to geometric series, but I didn't manage
to get to any geometric series.

Comment: What is $cis$? ${}{}$

Comment: @Norbert - $cis(\theta):=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Prove that
   $$
   \frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin^k(x)}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\left(\frac{e^{i x}}{\sin x}\right)^k-\left(\frac{e^{-i x}}{\sin x}\right)^k\right)
   $$
2. Recall geometric series formula.